# OpenTok - How to unsubscribe manually?

Tags: api, opentok, videochat, tokbox, video-conferencing

I have asked a related question before

[OpenTok - How to publish/unpublish manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008078/opentok-how-to-publish-unpublish-manually)

Now I am struggling to do the unsubscribe manually.

http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/tools/js/documentation/api/Session.html#unsubscribe

I have already followed the code but I still see the video. It is supposed to remove the video right?

EDIT: I discovered a mistake in the example code in the unsubscribe section. unsubscribe() accepts subscriber objects but the code passes a stream object.

Comment: Paste the code you have so far

Comment: Looks like the issue is fixed now, want to mark the question complete?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has the some error, heres some sample code snippet:
`var subscriber;`

After you create a subscriber:
`subscriber = session.subscribe( streamObject );`

To unsubscribe:
`session.unsubscribe(subscriber);`

Comment: it works. sadly, the documentation says the object you should pass to unsubscribe is the stream object

Comment: Yep, 2019 and the documentation still states to pass the stream and not the subscriber.

Comment: @Eldelshell I looked up the documentation and it says `subscriber` now. Perhaps the explanation could be better. Source: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html#unsubscribe